# Best way to loop through indexDb using ydn-db

Tags: ios, sql, mobile, indexeddb, ydn-db

I'm using ydn-db as a shim for mobile dev but am experiencing some poor performance with IOS and record retrieval.

My question is, what is the best way to loop over a data store?

Right now I use

db.values() and set the limit to the number of items in the list ( usually about 200, but it has a hard limit at 100 )

Anyhow was just wondering what the best way to go about looping over the results might be.

I have read the docs, and while they are extensive they are also confusing, hence why I'm posting here.

Anyhow, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to loop through is `db.open`. It iterate one record at a time and very memory efficient.